# puzzled with how to convert ddmmyy string to dd-MMM-yy date

Tags: java, date

I am puzzled with how to convert ddmmyy string to dd-MMM-yy date in java code.Example--

041110 as a string will be 04-NOV-10 as date.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can edit your question so you dont have to comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Something like

```
DateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
DateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String result = output.format(input.parse(inputString));
```

Comment: thanks, but if i provide 300201 or 300200 i get weired dates :(

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @godin The modern classes used in [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712040/5772882) with default settings will throw an exception when they get illegal dates like February 30. I agree with you that this is desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

The other Answers using `SimpleDateFormat` are outmoded now. Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead.

```
LocalDate.parse(
    "041110" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuu" , Locale.US ) 
)
.format( 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" , Locale.US )
)
```

> 04-Nov-10

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
String input = "041110" ;
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your desired output. Note that we specify the `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms in generating the name of the month.

```
DateTimeFormatter fParse = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuu" , Locale.US ) ;
```

Parse the input to get a `LocalDate` object. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , fParse ) ;
```

Generate a `String` in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

> ld.toString(): 2010-11-04

We have a `LocalDate` object in hand. We want to generate a String to represent that same value in another format.

```
DateTimeFormatter fGenerate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" , Locale.US ) ;
```

Generate the String object.

```
String output = ld.format( fGenerate ) ;
```

> 04-Nov-10

## Tips

Generally best to let java.time automatically localize rather than hard-code a formatting pattern as seen here. Instead, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.

Avoid the legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`. They are an awful mess of poor design. They were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes for many good reasons.

When exchanging data, never use custom formats such as that seen in the Question. Use the standard formats. They are designed to be unambiguous, easy to read by humans, and easy to parse by machine.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

use SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")

Answer (score 1):

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String s = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat or have a map that translates numbers 1-12 to month name abbreviations.

Comment: By the way… (a) Java 8 and later provides the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum, so no need to define your own. That class can localize month name. Ditto for `DayOfWeek`. (b) FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).